# How are "Closures" such a powerful abstraction that object systems and fundamental control structures are implemented using it?

Tags: scala, groovy, closures

Here is a quote from [programming scala](http://programming-scala.labs.oreilly.com/ch01.html) chapter 1:

> Closures are such a powerful abstraction that object systems and fundamental control structures are often implemented using them

Apparently the statement is not specifically about Scala but Closures in general but I can not
make much sense from it. Perhaps it is some pearl of wisdom only meant for those mighty compiler writers!

So who uses Closures to implement fundamental control structures and why?

**Edit:** I remember reading something about custom control structures in groovy "using the closure as the last parameter of method call" syntax and making the structure available to your code using meta-classes or `use` keyword with [Categories](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/GROOVY/Groovy+Categories). Could it be something related?

**Edit:** I found the following reference of the groovy custom control structures syntax [here](http://www.slideshare.net/gr8conf/gr8conf-practical-groovy-dsl) (slide 38):

> **Custom control structures**
>
> *Thanks to closures*
>
> - When closures are last, they can be    put “out” of the parentheses
>   surrounding parameters
> - `unless(account.balance > 100.euros, {    account.debit 100.euros })`
> - `unless(account.balance > 100.euros) {    account.debit 100.euros }`
> - Signature `def unless(boolean b,    Closure c)`

Apparently what groovy is offering is a syntactic sugar for making the Closure based custom control structures appear like first-class control structures offered by the language itself.

Comment: Take a look at languages like IO where they make heavy use of closures.

Comment: Also, collection methods in ruby, like 'each' make use of closures.

Comment: @jsuereth Answers usually go in the "answers" section. :-)

Comment: Partial answer - in Smalltalk, the if-else control structure is implemented as a method on the Boolean type and takes two closures as its parameters.  You could theoretically do the same thing in Scala, but the if-else structure is already built in.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I commented on the case of control structures. Let me comment on closures as objects. Consider what happens when you call a method on an object; it has access not only to the argument list, but also the fields of the object. That is, the method/function closes over the fields. This isn't that different from a "bare" function (i.e., not an object method) that closes over variables in scope. However, the object syntax provides a nice abstraction and modularity mechanism.

For example, I could write

```
case class Welcome(message: String) {
  def greet(name: String) = println(message + ", " + name)
}
val w = Welcome("Hello")
w.greet("Dean")
```

vs.

```
val message = "Hello"
val greet = (name: String) => println(message + ", " + name)
greet("Dean")
```

Actually, in this example, I could remove the "case" keyword from Welcome, so that message doesn't become a field, but the value is still in scope:

```
class Welcome2(message: String) {    // removed "case"
  def greet(name: String) = println(message + ", " + name)
}
val w = new Welcome2("Hello")        // added "new"
w.greet("Dean")
```

It still works! Now greet closes over the value of the input parameter, not a field.

```
var welcome = "Hello"
val w2 = new Welcome2(welcome)
w2.greet("Dean")     // => "Hello, Dean"
welcome = "Guten tag"
w2.greet("Dean")     // => "Hello, Dean"  (even though "welcome" changed)
```

But if the class refers to a variable in the outer scope directly,

```
class Welcome3 {                  // removed "message"
  def greet(name: String) = println(welcome + ", " + name) // reference "welcome"
}
val w3 = new Welcome3
w3.greet("Dean")                  // => "Guten tag, Dean"
welcome = "Buon giorno"
w3.greet("Dean")                  // => "Buon giorno, Dean"
```

Make sense?

Comment: The analogy of closures closing over scope variables to methods closing over their object's fields is illuminating.

Comment: @Adrian Fritsch: a closure is just an object with only one method. A method is just a closure over an object. The two are basically duals: an object is data with attached functions, a closure is a function with attached data.

Answer (score 3):

There are three fundamental control structures:

#### Sequence

```
a = 1
b = 2
c = a + b
```

#### Conditions

```
if (a != b) {
  c = a + b
} else {
  c = a - b
}
```

#### Iterations/loops

```
for (a <- array) {
  println(a)
}
```

So, I guess they mean that internally many languages use closures for control structures (you can look the last two structures).

As an example:

```
if (a < b) {
  for (i = a; a < b; a++) {
    println(i)
    c = i * i
  }
} else {
  c = a - b
}
```

So `for` is a closure inside the `if` closure, and `else` is a closure too. That's how I understand it. They create a closure for the first `if` if the condition is true, create the closure inside the braces, call it. Then create a closure for the `for` loop and call it while the condition is true.

And I guess there is no list of languages which use closures internally.

Update:

Just as an example, this is how you can implement your own `for` loop in Scala (o is cyrillic, so it will compile):

```
def fоr(start: Unit, condition: => Boolean, increment: => Unit)(body: => Unit): Unit = {
  if (condition) {
    body
    increment
    fоr(0, condition, increment)(body)
  }
}

var i = 0

fоr (i = 0, i < 1000, i += 1) {
  print(i + " ")
}
```

So actually this is how it can be implemented in other languages on the inner level.

Comment: Thanks stam, but your example appears to be about variable scopes in general. Whereas the page I referenced defines closures as: "Closures are functions that reference variables from the scope enclosing the function definition."

Comment: Well, if you write `c = a + i` in the `for` loop and enclose the condition in another `for` loop where `a` gets declared, it will reference `a` from the enclosing scope, while `a` itself will be accessed only in the enclosing `for` closure. It's all about variable scopes, but the point is that “many” languages create closures for loops and conditional structures, not just plainly repeating or skipping lines of code and looking if the variable is inside or outside the scope.

Comment: Actually, the definition of fundamental control structures may very. Forth has three: sequences, conditional and unconditional branches. Every other control structure is implemented through them.

Comment: @Daniel C. Sobral “Every other control structure is implemented through them” implies that there are three *fundamental* control structures.

Comment: @Stam. So you are saying that the above definition of Closure is defining the closure as it is available to Scala programmer while the quote under discussion uses it in wider sense (i-e not just functions but any piece of code accessing variables from other scopes). I am still doubtful of this understanding because in nested loops you can only access the enclosing scope that is still in effect whereas function closures can access variables from scopes that are no more in effect.

Comment: @Tahir Akhtar I wrote how I understand the phrase from the book. I don't know the underlying implementation of `if`s and `for`s in “many languages” and why they use or don't use out-of-scope variables. They don't have to be the closures as they are exposed to you in languages that support them on the developer level. But even in languages which don't allow you to create/use closures these control structures can still be inside implemented in closures.

Comment: @Tahir Akhtar the best way to find out what authors mean is to ask them directly :)

Comment: I wrote the quote, so I guess I should explain myself ;) I didn't mean that most languages actually implement control structures this way, just that many could. To use a simple example, a while loop could be implemented as a function that takes a boolean argument (in Scala, you would want to use a "by-name" parameter) and a "block" that is executed for each iteration. In Scala, the block would be a function literal (a.k.a. anonymous function) This function could reference values in the enclosing scope, thereby becoming a closure.

Comment: @stam I said the definition of fundamental control structures may vary. I never denied that there's multiple possible sets of control structures from which all others may be derived.

Comment: There is one fundamental control structure, the continuation. All other control structures can be implemented with it. The reverse is not true (except in the sense that one can combine jumps and datastructures to create any higher-level programming artifact).

Answer (score 1):

I would say that "*closures are such a powerful abstraction...*" because unlike standard methods, you have a reference to the calling object, regardless of the scope in which the closure has been called.

In Groovy, for example, you can add a new method, "capitalize" to String type:

```
String.metaClass.capitalize = {  
    delegate[0].upper() + delegate[1..-1].lower()  
}   
"hello".capitalize() // "Hello"
```

Or, you can do something more complex, like create a domain specific language (DSL) using closures.

```
class ClosureProps {

       Map props = [:]  
       ClosureProps(Closure c) {  
           c.delegate = this // pass closure scope to "this"
           c.each{"$it"()} // iterate through closure, triggering missingMethod()
       }  
       def methodMissing(String name, args) {  
           props[name] = args.collect{it} // collect extracted closure properties
       }  
       def propertyMissing(String name) {  
           name  
       }  
}
```

**Example**

```
class Team {

        // the closure
        static schema = {  
            table team  
            id teamID  
            roster column:playerID, cascade:[update,delete]  
        }  
}  
def c = new ClosureProps(Team.schema)  
println c.props.id // prints "teamID"
```

Answer (score -5):

a) Please try at least googling topics before asking questions.

b) Once you have done that, please ask specific questions.

c) Lexical closures are functions that have access to a lexical environment not available where they are invoked. As such, their parameters can be used to select messages, and pass parameters with those messages. For general control structures, they are not sufficient, unless they can affect the call stack, in the manner of continuations.

Comment: Care to read the question again and explain how your rant is relevant? As far as I can see the question is very specific. I do know what Closures are, having used them in JavaScript and Groovy. If you are sure about your last statement then do you think the statement " ... fundamental control structures are often implemented using them" is incorrect?

Comment: Actually this site has no problem with duplicating content that already exists elsewhere in the web.

Comment: @Tahir: It's relevant because it a) answers your question b) suggests other high quality ways of getting information on this topic, no doubt more full (although perhaps less pithy) than you would get here.